# Link form a Text to a Bar-Code in ZebraDesigner

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I would like to "Link" a Text to a Bar-Code. If the text changes, the Bar-Code should update itself.
In use is the ZebraDesigner in Version 2.5.0 Build 9384 and the printer is a Zebra S4M.

[I couldn't find any options for a link from a Text to a Bar-Code. In the picture, the 150 is changing and the Bar-Code should update its value automatically.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQSJv.png)